# Videos URL structure with nothing but a date in it to keep every video shareable?

Tags: url, structure, typo3, share

what is the approach to store multiple videos from an author in his named folder, but then there are 1-n videos from this author?

YouTube has for every video a complete different URL with an ID. Casual/Older users don't know where they are.

News sites seem use `/topic/title-id123`
Cnn uses `/yyyy/mm/dd/title`

**To keep this question answerable: What URL structure would you recommend for me?**
- every person has some videos without interesting title we could use
- the date from start day to end day is more likely important (2005-12-12 to 2005-12-17)
- every video should be social media shareable, so I think they all need a single URL and can't just be all embedded in /videos/name

Comment: I still don't get the question
- How are videos stored in TYPO3? Which extension, ..
- What does storing videos have to do with the URL
- Which TYPO3 version

Comment: Ups. It is version 6. Videos are plain mp4 on the same hosted server where the website is. Videos are in fileadmin/videos if that is a good way to store them. No extensions. I chosed JW Player to play them.

I would create a new page with a "plain html" element and put the player code in that element.

But I can't come up with a smart url structure to have every single video on it's own url...

I think about something like domain.tld/videos/name/date, but I want to hear other opinions on that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them however is the best for the backend editor workflow (you didn't mention, how and when new videos are added), in 6.2 you have file abstraction layer, so each file in fileadmin has assigned ID. If you want to make your videos nicely social media sharable, you need to provide additional metadata such as video name and thumbnail etc, so I would suggest building a plugin for this which would take the video ID from the URL and display it with all the additional data necessary.

If you are using EXT:realurl (which I hope you are), you can configure to the video title in the URL, which would look like: `/somepage/video/video-title/` or even `/somepage/video-title/` . Adding `/yyyy/mm/dd/` in the URL only makes sense if you are producing multiple videos every day, otherwise it feels pointless.

Answer (score 0):

for building unique URLs with realurl for news you find solutions to include the uid of the news.
As TYPO3 handles all files with FAl you might use the unique file_sys:uid  in your video URL. You might use realurl to generate and resolve URLs like:

```
/videos/123/title_of_video/
```